# Multiple optional parameters routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, url-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following route definition in my webapi project. I have problem one of the parameter is not passed. eg;

when i call /Controller/Action/param2/startdate/enddate the value i passed for param2 is taken for param1 and vice versa.The problem is, the RoutingModule can not detect that the provided route value is for param2 not param1

It works if i use querystring in the url but doesn't want to use querystring. Appreciate your help.

Is there any way to achieve what i expect?

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RetrieveHistory",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/{startDate}/{endDate}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Vend",
        action = "RetrieveUtrnHistory",
        param1 = RouteParameter.Optional,
        param2 = RouteParameter.Optional,
        starDate = RouteParameter.Optional,
        endDate = RouteParameter.Optional
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: If you see an URL with a missing parameter, how do you know which is the missing parameter? If you can give me an answer to this question (how do YOU know it), I can help you create a set of routes that will allow you to do what you want. If you are not able to do that, you can still change the way of writing URLs, and I can still help you. So please, update the question either with an answer to my first questions, or showing some sample URLs and telling what parameter mathcing you expect for each of them. There are ways to achiveve what you need, but you must explain it clearly.

Comment: I dont know that why i have posted question here. i am not very well experienced with Routing

Comment: I'm not asking you howto route... I'm just asking you how you know the URLs are different as a "human being". I'll give you some ideas...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To solve your problem you must take into account this things:

- you can register more than one route. The first registered route that can handle an URL, will handle it.
- you can use something apart from slash `/` as separator, to make parts of a route distinguishable
- you can use parameter constraints, usually regular expressions, to make it easier to discover if a parameter is of one or other kind
- you can specify default values for your parameters, and, if you do so, the action method must have default values for them (unless MVC, that only requires them to be nullable or of reference type)

As you didn't tell how your URL looks like I'll show you my own examples.

Let's suppose that you have a `TestController` Web API Controller class with an action like this:

```
// GET api/Test/TestAction/ ...
[HttpGet]
public object TestAction(int param1, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, 
                         int? param2 = null)
{
    return new
    {
        param1 = param1,
        param2 = param2,
        startDate = startDate,
        endDate = endDate
    }.ToString();
}
```

*NOTE: with the default routes a Web API controller's method named `GetXxx` is available to HTTP GET, a method named `PostXxx` is available to HTTP POST and so on. However, once you include `Controller` and `Action` in the URL template, you must use the `[HttpXxx]` attributes to make your method available to the required HTTP method.*

#### Optional parameter(s) in the middle

In this first example, I suppose that both `param1`, and `param2` are integer numbers, and `stardDate` and `endDate` are dates:

```
http://myhost/api/Mycontroller/Myaction/12/22/2014-12-01/2014-12-31
http://myhost/api/Mycontroller/Myaction/22/2014-12-01/2014-12-31
```

If you want the first URL to match parameters like these:

```
param1 = 12; param2 = 22; startDate = 2014-12-01; endData = 2014-12-31
```

and the second like these:

```
param1 = 12; param2 = null; startDate = 2014-12-01; endData = 2014-12-31
```

You need to register two routes, one that will match each possible URL structure, i.e.

```
// for the 1st
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/{startDate}/{endDate}"
// for the 2nd
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{startDate}/{endDate}"
```

Note that, in this case, both routes are mutually exclusive, i.e. a single URL can match only one of the routes, so you can register them in any other.

However, you must notice that the second URL doesn't define a value for `param2`, and the `TestAction` method requires it. This wouldn't work: you must include a default value for this parameter, both in the controler's method and in the route registration:

- action parameter `int? param2 = null` (C# requires optional parameter to be the last ones).
- the route must include the default: `defaults: new { param2 = RouteParameter.Optional }`

This is the way to solve the optional parameter in the middle problem. In general, you'll need to define several routes, depending on how many optional parameters there are, and declare this parameters, with default values, in the Web API action method.

NOTE: as I wrote above, in MVC you don't need to specify a default value in the method parameter for this to work

#### Parameter constraints

Specifying constrains for a route parameter has two consequences:

1. There's a warranty that the parameter value has the expected format
2. Most importantly, the route will only handle the URL if the format is the expected one. So this helps you make your URL more selective, thus making it more flexible.

You simply need to add a `constraint` parameter on the route registration, like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Multiparam2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/{startDate}/{endDate}",
    constraints: new
    {
        startDate = @"20\d\d-[0-1]?\d-[0-3]?\d", // regex
        endDate = @"20\d\d-[0-1]?\d-[0-3]?\d" // regex
    },
    defaults: new object { }
);
```

Note that it's necessary to specify a `defaults` parameter, even if it's empty.

*NOTE: the constraints in this case are a regex that only matches dates in the year 20XX, the month expressed as a single digit, or as 0x or 1x, and the date as a single digit or 0x, 1x, 2x or 3x, separated by dashes. So this regex  will match `2012-1-1` or `2015-12-30`, but not `1920-12-30`. You should adapt the regex to your needs.*

#### Optional parameters at the end

By this time I've explained how to support optional parameters, and how to specify formats (constraints) for them, to match a route template.

The usual way to define optional parameters is to do it at the end of the URL template, and, in this case, if there are missing params in a route, they must be all at the end of the route. (Compare this with optional in the middle: they require different routes).

In this example, if you want to make optional the `param2`, and the `startDate` and `endDate`, you must define them in the route registration, and set default parameter values in the action method.

The final code would look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public object TestAction(int param1, int? param2 = null, DateTime? startDate = null, 
                         DateTime? endDate = null)
{
    return new
    {
        param1 = param1,
        param2 = param2,
        startDate = startDate,
        endDate = endDate
    }.ToString();
}



config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Multiparam1",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{startDate}/{endDate}",
    constraints: new
    {
        startDate = @"20\d\d-[0-1]?\d-[0-3]?\d",
        endDate = @"20\d\d-[0-1]?\d-[0-3]?\d"
    },
    defaults: new
    {
        param2 = RouteParameter.Optional,
        startDate = RouteParameter.Optional,
        endDate = RouteParameter.Optional
    }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Multiparam2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/{startDate}/{endDate}",
    constraints: new
    {
        startDate = @"(20\d\d-[0-1]?\d-[0-3]?\d)?",
        endDate = @"(20\d\d-[0-1]?\d-[0-3]?\d)?"
    },
    defaults: new
    {
        startDate = RouteParameter.Optional,
        endDate = RouteParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Note, that, in this case:

1. the routes could be mismatched, so they must be registered in the right order, as shown. If you registered first the `Multiparam2` route, it would erroneously handle an URL like this: `http://localhost:1179/api/test/testaction/1/2014-12-12/2015-1-1`, with `param1=1; param2="2014-12-12"; startDate="2015-1-1"`. (You could avoid this with an additional constraint on param2 that only accepts numbers, like `param2=@"\d+"`)
2. the action must have default values for `startDate` and `endDate`.

#### Conclusions

You can handle default parameters in different positions by carefully:

- registering routes in the right order
- define default parameters in the route, and also default values in the controller's action
- use constraints

If you plan carefully how your routes look like, you can get what you need with a few routes and optional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

JotaBe answer was nice and complete. Just you have to consider if parameters are optional you have to write routeTemplate with the order from lowest parameters to highest.

Just like :

```
// for the 1st
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{startDate}/{endDate}"

// for the 2nd
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/{startDate}/{endDate}"
```